# How to write program for control robot arm?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**I need help about step by step to write a program from first to last, ROS packages for used in this application so that specify the position of robot arm.**

**ex.**

1. Write a program for control hardware (Motor Control) Node.
2. Use joint_state_publisher to ....blah blah blah ...........
3. ....................................................................................

I need more details about in a beginner level for control forward kinematic of robot arm following the joint variables and I should write PID control in hardware node or other or not?

**Thank you for all answers**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52256/how-to-write-program-for-control-robot-arm?/) by [Soda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3104/soda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a great tutorial for what you want to do:

> [www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/Running%20arm%20navigation%20on%20non-PR2%20arm](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/Running%20arm%20navigation%20on%20non-PR2%20arm)

---

Originally posted by [isura](https://answers.ros.org/users/1583/isura/) with karma: 403 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Soda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3104/soda/) on 2013-01-29**:
I need more details about in a beginner level for control forward kinematic of robot arm following the joint variables and I should write PID control in hardware node or other or not?

**Comment by [isura](https://answers.ros.org/users/1583/isura/) on 2013-02-08**:
This answer by Martin Günther may be of some help in getting started: http://answers.ros.org/question/12182/controllers-vs-drivers/#18025